# Angular directive not detected

Tags: angular

I have this really basic directive:

```
import { Directive, QueryList, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[pyb-fixed-table]'
})
export class FixedTableDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('pybFixedTable') productTableElement: ElementRef;
  @Input('description') descriptionElements: QueryList<ElementRef> = new QueryList

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
    console.log('resize');
    this.addFixedClass();
    this.setElementWidths();
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addFixedClass();
    this.setElementWidths();
  }

  private addFixedClass() {
    console.log(this.productTableElement);
  }

  private setElementWidths(): void {
    let tableWidth = this.productTableElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(tableWidth);
    this.descriptionElements.forEach((element: ElementRef) => {
      let cell = element.nativeElement;
      if (!cell) return;

      cell.style.maxWidth = `${tableWidth}px`;
    });
  }
}
```

It is declared in my **Shared.Module** and I have exported it.
If I use it in my component like this:

```
<div pyb-fixed-table>
```

everything is fine.
But if I do this:

```
<div [pyb-fixed-table]="productTable">
```

I get an error:

> Can't bind to 'pyb-fixed-table' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

If I change to this:

```
<div pyb-fixed-table="productTable">
```

It seems to work, but it isn't passing my input.
My input is a reference:

```
  <div pyb-fixed-table="productTable" *ngIf="rows">
    <div class="table-responsive" #productTable>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`@Input('pybFixedTable') productTableElement: ElementRef;`

to

```
@Input('pyb-fixed-table') productTableElement: ElementRef;
```

and try

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 <div pyb-fixed-table [productTableElement]="productTable" *ngIf="rows">
```